# How can I override solution's aspnetcompiler.targetpath from the commandline?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I'm calling 
`MSBUILD.exe \pathtosolution\solution.sln  /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputDir=\pathfordlls\ /p:WebProjectOutputDir=\pathtocompileto\`

When it finishes compiling the DLLs into the correct directory and calls aspnet_compiler,I am expecting it to use the WebProjectOutputDir - but it is using the directory specified inside of the solution file
`Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\lidacweb\`

What do I need to do to make it accept that argument? Am I missing something?

Comment: what kind of project is the website?